# ¿Existe un equivalente en español para "foo", "bar", "baz"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico

En programación es usual encontrar los términos *foobar*, *foo*, *bar*, *baz* y *qux* como variables metasintácticas (*placeholders*, en inglés) que sirven para referirse a variables, funciones o a comandos cuyo fin principal es demostrar un concepto. ¿Existen términos equivalentes en español para estas variables metasintácticas?

Comment: Me temo que es una de esas situaciones en las que al predominar el inglés en la informática, muchas veces no hace falta ni traducción siquiera.

Comment: @JoulSauron yo también lo temo, pero quiero asegurarme ;-)

Comment: Mis propios profesores usan ``foo``, ``bar``, etc. y de momento no me he topado con ninguna traducción convincente.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

En principio, son nombres de variables que se usan solamente con sus términos en inglés.

El que escribió el artículo en castellano sobre "Foo" en la Wikipedia, da un ejemplo de cómo podría ser en español el equivalente, con nombres como *fulano*, *mengano*, *citano*...

Es decir, en realidad podríamos decir que no, no hay equivalente a *foo*, *foobar*... en español, por lo menos nadie ha dicho esta boca es mía.

Quizá lo más equivalente sería el `pruebaXX` donde XX es un número. Al menos yo he visto mucho programador en España que en vez de usar el `foo` para lo que se usa, se dedica a usar el `prueba01`, `prueba02`... en sustitución, y debo admitir que incluso yo lo he hecho.

Pero este tipo de variables suele usarse solo en códigos de pruebas, en los que el concepto de la variable queda desvirtuado y no significa nada, cosa que no pasa con `foo`, que siempre intenta demostrar un concepto.

---

Añado: Entre @JoulSauron y yo estamos llegando a la conclusión final, que no existiría traducción posible para el conjunto de palabras `foo`, `bar` para designar nombres a variables metasintácticas.

Comment: No sé si se suele usar, pero en la carrera usábamos var1, var2... sobre todo en ejercicios cortos.

Comment: Es otra forma de trabajar como lo que se hace en `prueba1, `prueba2`, aún y así vas a escuchar a mucha gente decirte que eso de numerar las variables es totalmente incorrecto, que cada variable debe llamarse por algo que la identifique, y por eso en inglés aparecen las `foo` y demás, para evitar la numeración de las variables. Como ya he dicho sería nuestro equivalente en nombres a `zutanito`, `menganito`; porque no vamos llamando a la gente de ejemplo `persona1` o `persona2`

Comment: Sí, pero la verdad es que tampoco usamos usamos los "fulano" y "mengano" en código, pero al menos yo no lo he visto. Como he comentado en la pregunta, la mayoría usamos `foo, bar` porque programamos en inglés.

Comment: Ya hombre, pero `fulano` y `mengano` son ejemplos del `foo` o `bar` para nombres de personas. Yo creo que será más un estandar que se ha utilizado así porque los que lo originaron fueron de habla inglesa. Es decir al final, no tendríamos nuestra equivalencia en el idioma de Cervantes. Que le vamos a hacer no se puede tener todo en esta vida :D

Answer (score -1):

there might not be a great answer, in Spanish it might be "cualquier cosa", but I will really get an understanding as a meta-equivalent of something, or "anything", but there are different ways of understanding the same language, either English, Spanish or others...