# «Placeholder words» en castellano

Tags: traducción, sustantivos

En el uso cotidiano nos encontramos a menudo con sustantivos que refieren a objetos cuyo nombre no recordamos o que no importa porque se entiende inmediatamente por contexto. Son un subconjunto de lo que en inglés se llaman "[placeholder names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name)" o "placeholder words". El más común en castellano debe ser *cosa* y sus diminutivos, pero seguramente hay muchísimos más. ¿Cómo se llaman formalmente estas palabras (y no, no son [variables metasintácticas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/existe-un-equivalente-en-espa%C3%B1ol-para-foo-bar-baz))? ¿Cuáles serían algunos ejemplos significativos? (La idea no es compilar una lista. P. S. Me entero por comentario que [ya hay una](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15026/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-palabra-para-algo-que-no-se-sabe-c%C3%B3mo-decir).)

Como anécdota diré que esta pregunta se me ocurrió anoche mientras leía un estudio sobre el Quijote donde se comentaba que con tal o cual novela Cervantes había "retornado al coso literario", lo cual me provocó risa porque *coso* es una variable de esta clase en rioplatense (como *thingie* en inglés, *negócio* en portugués) que [no aparece en el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B5ksQqZ%7CB5mtsUv).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yo siempre he oído llamarlas [palabras comodín](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Palabra_comod%C3%ADn) aunque no se si es exactamente lo mismo

Comment: Ay Pablo me encantan las imágenes.

Comment: @aparente001 Acabo de cambiar una porque el señor ferretero no había entendido el sistema.

Comment: Lástima -- también estaba muy bien.... // Quizás *espacios para rellenar*.

Comment: En [¿Cuál es la palabra para algo que no se sabe cómo decir?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/15027/1674) guifa recogió unas cuantas. No sé si es exactamente el tipo de palabras que buscas.

Comment: @fedorqui Son exactamente ésas. Faltaría saber si tienen un nombre. (Una de las razones por las cuales no encontré esa otra pregunta es que no sabía cómo referirme a ellas.)

Comment: ¿Seguro que no son *palabras comodín*? https://cvc.cervantes.es/ensenanza/biblioteca_ele/asele/pdf/16/16_0396.pdf

Comment: @blonfu podrías publicar una respuesta proponiendo _palabras comodín_ ? Yo creo que estás en lo correcto, aunque siempre puede haber respuestas adicionales que sean más o menos precisas, o que propongan un término adicional para esas... _cosas_. Y que la gente vote para apoyar la validez de cada propuesta.

Comment: @Diego Al principio lo he puesto como comentario porque no estaba seguro pero viendo la otra pregunta de guifa y otras fuentes creo que puede ser un término válido. Intentaré redactarlo como una respuesta

Comment: Pablo, ¿no te gusta *marcador de posición* que me dió linguee?

Comment: @aparente001 Parece bastante literal y muy técnico (no sé cómo le suena *placeholder* a un hablante nativo de inglés pero asumo que no es un término extraño).

Comment: O sea, ¿temes que "marcador de posición" no se entienda comúnmente, y te preguntas si "placeholder" sufre de ese problema también?  Con respecto a "marcador de posición," no sé si se entendería bien; "placeholder" se entiende bastante bien en inglés, pero eso sí, "fill in the blank", usado como adjetivo, se entiende mejor aún.  Por eso propuse *espacios para rellenar* -- pero no sé si eso se entendería en la práctica.  No he usado ese término en conversación yo en lo personal.

Comment: @aparente001 "Marcador de posición" me sugiere un señalador (*bookmark*) como el que uno pone entre las páginas de un libro para saber dónde se quedó. No me sugiere un espacio para rellenar.

Comment: Bueno, solo propuse "marcador de posición" porque linguee.com me lo propuso.  ¿Qué opinas de "espacios para rellenar"? // A propósito, ¿podrías poner un ejemplo de una frase con un espacio para rellenar donde iría el término que buscas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No he conseguido encontrar en la *Gramática* de la RAE un nombre concreto para este tipo de palabras; eso sí, he averiguado que la palabra *cosa* aparece en prácticamente todas las páginas de la misma.

Lo que sí he visto, siguiendo la propuesta de @blonfu, es que en un par de ocasiones menciona que existen palabras "que se usan a modo de comodines". No cita expresamente el caso de *cosa*, pero al menos sí que usa una expresión que nos resulta familiar. A fin de cuentas:

> **[comodín, na](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9xkqf5p)**
>
> ```
> De cómodo.
> ```
>
> 3. m. Persona o cosa que sirve para fines diversos, según la conveniencia de quien dispone de ella.

Consultando otras fuentes, veo que Wikilengua sí [contiene una definición](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Palabra_comod%C3%ADn) para este tipo de palabras:

> Se llama palabra comodín a la que se emplea con multitud de sentidos reemplazando a otras que son más precisas y adecuadas en un determinado contexto.

Tampoco cita el caso concreto de *cosa*, de hecho se centra más en algunos verbos. Sí que se cita la palabra *cosa* como la palabra comodín más usada en [esta otra página web](http://ortografia.com.es/una-palabra-comodin/), que dice:

> Una palabra comodín es aquella que posee un significado muy general y por tanto, susceptible de ser utilizada en gran variedad de contextos.

Y curiosamente da otra opción para llamar a estas palabras (negritas mías):

> También se suele utilizar el término "**palabra bául**".

Cita como ejemplo el verbo *poner*, que se usa en multitud de casos con distinto significado:

> Ya me han *puesto* la fibra óptica -> instalar.
>   *Pon* estos libros por orden alfabético -> colocar.

No encuentro en la *Gramática* referencias al concepto de "palabras baúl", pero sí que se encuentran multitud de referencias a este término en la red. Por ejemplo:

- ["Cosas" y otras palabras baúl](http://nadiaorenes.es/blog/2015/07/cosas-y-otras-palabras-baul/)
- [PALABRAS BAÚL, 1. Verbos hacer, dejar y poner](https://www.victoriamonera.com/palabras-baul-1/)
- [LAS PALABRAS BAÚL](https://prezi.com/42n8mx2uqte7/las-palabras-baul/)
- [PALABRAS COMODÍN, BAÚL O MULTIUSO](http://lperezcerra.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/palabras-comodin-baul-o-multiuso.html)

Acabo con la definición de *cosa*, que me ha parecido curiosa (sobre todo la primera acepción):

> **[cosa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B3yTydM)**
>
> ```
> Del lat. causa 'causa, motivo'.
> ```
>
> 1. f. Lo que tiene entidad, ya sea corporal o espiritual, natural o artificial, concreta, abstracta o virtual.
> 2. f. Objeto inanimado, por oposición a ser viviente.
> 3. f. Asunto, tema o negocio.

Answer (score 3):

Lo puse en los comentarios y también lo ha mencionado @Charlie en su respuesta, un término que puede utilizarse para definir las palabras genéricas que se utilizan como reemplazo de otras es **palabras comodín**.

Además de la ya mencionada, en otra respuesta, entrada de wikilengua hay una serie de artículos en Fundéu con el título *LA PALABRA: COMODINES* en los que pone ejemplos de este tipo de palabras usadas en Venezuela:

- [LA PALABRA: COMODINES
  (1)](https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/la-palabra-comodines-1-6815/)
- [LA PALABRA: COMODINES
  (2)](https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/la-palabra-comodines-2-6824/)
- [LA PALABRA: COMODINES
  (3)](https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/la-palabra-comodines-3-6830/)

Pongo esos tres como ejemplo aunque hay alguno más, creo que seis.

No encuentro el término en fuentes "oficiales" pero si en muchos artículos o webs sobre lengua, en [esta](http://lenguacastellanayliteratura-tercerciclo-educacionprimaria.mex.tl/1082697_Onomatopeyas---Palabras-Comodin.html) por ejemplo dice:

> Se llaman **palabras comodín**,  denominadas también palabras **cliché** o palabras **baúl**, a las que se emplea con multitud de sentidos reemplazando a otras que son más precisas y adecuadas en un determinado contexto.